# How do I add time to a Windows batch command %time% output?

Tags: windows, batch-file, time, command, prompt

I have a batch file that will loop in 4 hours. I would like to display the time 4 hours (or 14400 seconds) from now.

```
@echo off
cls

title My Batch File

set looptime=14400

:loopme

set nextlooptime=%time%+%looptime%    

echo This command prompt will loop in 4 hours, at %nextlooptime%.

TIMEOUT /T %looptime% /NOBREAK

goto loopme
```

The output is not as expected.

"This command prompt will loop in 4 hours, at 10:51:09.62+14400.

Waiting for 13656 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ..."

I'd like it to display the time 4 hours (or 14400 seconds) from %time%.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: you can't do calculations with times or dates in batch. You can do (limited) calculations with `set /a`. Basically, you'd need to transform the timestamp to a pure integer (number of seconds), add the looptime and transform the resulting integer back to a timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call out to Powershell rather easy to add hours to the current time and put it into a variable.

```
for /f "delims=" %%G IN ('powershell "(get-date %time%).AddHours(4).ToString('HH:mm:ss')"') do set endtime=%%G
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method. Assuming the intention is only to display to the user, seconds/milliseconds have been left out.

```
@echo off & color f0

:[ Retrieve the hours and minutes from the %time% variable and turn it into variables ]
set hour=%time:~0,2%
  if "%hour:~,1%"=="0" set hour=%hour:~1,2%
set minute=%time:~3,2%
:[ Being careful of leading zeros in set /a, as it indicates an octal value ]
  if "%minute:~,1%"=="0" set minute=%minute:~1,2%
:[ Here is where 4 hours are added ]
set /a hour+=4
:[ Minding the run over time ]
  if %minute% geq 60 set /a minute=%minute%-60 && set /a hour=%hour%+1
  if %hour% geq 24 set hour=00
  if %minute% lss 10 set minute=%minute%
  if %hour% lss 10 set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
echo Task will run at %hour%:%minute%
:[ If desired display is relative to 12; ]
  if %hour% gtr 12 set /a hour-=12
echo Alt display is %hour%:%minute%
pause
```

The `set /a` following `:[ Here is where 4 hours are added ]` can be adjusted to will.

Of course `set /a hour+=%addTime%` could be used if flexibility is desired.